# OpenID Connect Unable to verify JWT claims

Tags: php, openid-connect, openid

i have issue while implementing [Jumbojett OpenID](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP) Authentication. This is my code

```
$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient(
                $this->config->item('SSO_PROVIDER_URL'),
                $this->config->item('SSO_CLIENT_ID'),
                $this->config->item('SSO_CLIENT_SECRET')
            );
$oidc->setVerifyHost(false);    //dev only
$oidc->setVerifyPeer(false);    //dev only
$oidc->setHttpUpgradeInsecureRequests(false);   //dev only
$isAuthenticate = $oidc->authenticate();
```

The provider url in the config.php file doesn't have trailing slash.. It looks like this (redacted with *)

```
$config['SSO_PROVIDER_URL'] = 'https://auth.****.**.id/auth/realms/***ura-**st';
$config['SSO_CLIENT_ID'] = '***ola-****';
$config['SSO_CLIENT_SECRET'] = '********************************';
```

That code actually works in my local pc, but somehow when i deploy it on the server it keeps throwing me this error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClientException
> Message: Unable to verify JWT claims
> Filename: /var/www/html/vendor/jumbojett/openid-connect-php/src/OpenIDConnectClient.php
> Line Number: 373
> Backtrace:
> File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Welcome.php
> Line: 56
> Function: authenticate
> File: /var/www/html/index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Please help me, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the JWT claims fail to be verified is because `$claims->exp` and the server time `time()` on the verifyJWTClaims function in OpenIDConnectClient.php differs way past 5 minutes (the expiration time).
Because my server is centos 9, I synchronize the server time using chronyd and it works now.